# Unknown column in fieldlist for a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL with various fields one of which is in the `timestamp` format and it is called time, when I am trying

```
SELECT time
FROM transactions
```

And the **transactions table**

```
id (int)
time (timestamp)
amount (float)
```

[image]

I am getting an `Unknown column in fieldlist` error. Should I convert the time to string to be able to retrieve it? or how can I get all the timestamps?

Comment: @Alexander I just posted the structure of the table, its a small simple table. I am using MySQL in Apache using Xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks for this

```
SELECT `time`
  FROM transactions;
```

Comment: [*MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.6)

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a reserved or, at the very least a very sensative word in MySQL,
[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: [*MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.6)